# Does jshint understand Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

jshint is throwing an error when defining an angular module (or directive, or factory) as recommended by the Angular style guides (by [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide) or [Todd Motto](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide)). For example, for a controller like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myAppCtrl', theController);

    function theController() {...}

})();
```

... jshint throws this error:

```
'theController' was used before it was defined.
```

The angular app works perfectly despite these errors. However I don't know why jshint protests...

What am I missing? I wonder if jshint is a good evaluator of the quality of the angular code (despite it is included with popular packages as generator-angular) or it's me that I am doing something wrong (although my app works).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move your `theController` function definition above your angular code.  Modern JS engines will look ahead and find your function definition before executing, but older engines execute from top to bottom (and I think "strict" mode requires this too).

Comment: I thought function hoisting would make that not a problem

Comment: Does jshint understand JavaScript*. ANGULAR JS IS JAVASCRIPT. NOTHING MORE

Comment: The error isn't specific to Angular. You apparently have [JSHint's `latedef` option](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#latedef) enabled, which warns you about code that depends upon [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting). Either disable the option or adjust the order of statements in your code to remove the dependency.

Comment: @self In this case, `Angular [style] !== JavaScript`. John Papa (see [his answer to *this* question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26321623/1028230)) has what's apparently a [popular style guide for Angular](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide) that *requires* defining functions *after* they're used as parameters. That means Papa-sanctioned Angular style won't work with `latedef` set to true in JSHint, and *will never pass JSLint*. I might change the phrasing a bit ("Does John Papa grok JSLint?"), but David's is a fair question. Not a *great* title for the post, but a fair question.

Answer (score 18):

Use the `latedef` property and set it to `false`. This allows hoisting of functions, which IMO is fine. But still reports hoisting of vars, which is bad IMO

Comment: Why not make the concession to Crockford and [declare the function you're going to use first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27296661/1028230) before going back into your preferred flow and defining it? Then everyone [seems to be!] happy.

Comment: i prefer to keep the code that drives the intent up top, above the fold. putting the functions and interface up top does this. you can do it any way you like (that works). but this is why i do it: to make it instantly identifiable as i open the file as to what it does and how to use it. details follow

Comment: No, I get it. I'm saying that [the answer above does both -- follows your advice **and** lints](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27296661/1028230). You've got *one* trivial extra line to declare the function(s) to make linters happy, and then all the "details follow" as before. Your style guide carries weight, but its conflicts with linters is causing a couple of questions like this one on SO. The declaration line preserves your ideals a heck of a lot better than this question's [currently leading answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26288458/1028230) and would stop the lint conflicts. 2¢, etc.

Comment: I get it, but I don't see a reason to ad the extra line up top for the var when I can set latedef off. It is all based on that I do not feel hoisting of functions is bad.

Comment: Fair enough; thanks. Just don't expect [Douglas](http://www.crockford.com/) to like it. ;^)

Comment: LOL, I know. I respect the heck out of him too :)

Comment: So does this mean hoisting is always safe?  
Or is it only safe in newer browsers?  
BTW It seems like jshint does not report hoisting of vars anymore when 'latedef' is set to false.

Comment: It just refers to hoisting of functions, which I think is fine and is how my angular style guide shows it. Hoisting of vars is not good. So declare all vars up top.

Answer (score 15):

well first of include angular in your "globals variables", for example:

```
"globals": { // Global variables.
        "jasmine": true,
        "angular": true,
        "browser": true,
        "element": true,
        "by":true,
        "io":true,
        "_":false,
        "$":false
    }
```

then move your function definition before you reference it from angular.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function theController() {...}

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myAppCtrl', theController);
})();
```

Comment: Problem solved!! thanks for all the answers. @jack-the-ripper, it worked by just moving the definition of the function as you suggested. Anyway, I have also added "angular" to the globals in the .jshintrc file as you suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: the problem is the angular style guide advocates a style for defining the functions below then binding them to a public endpoint up top (ie `this.foo = internalFoo`... up top `function internalFoo() {}` at the bottom) https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Answer (score 5):

So another option, that makes every linter happy, is to declare the variable that'll hold the function first, use it as a param, and then define it.

But personally I'm not sure I love the flow here. I think I like jack's answer better, but this is a little closer to what Papa seems to prefer, if you're down with his [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide). Actually, I'm not sure why this isn't what he recommends, if he really wants functions to appear after they're used (and he does). Otherwise, you *can't* use his style with `latedef` set to true in JSHint -- or JSLint *at all*.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var theController;

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myAppCtrl', theController);


    theController = function () {
        return "so jslint doesn't complain about empty blocks";
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code *should* work, but jshint is going to try and get you to code in a very strict manner.  At the very least it's a "good practice" to have your functions defined before you use them.  As I mentioned in the comment above, I think older javascript engines execute from top to bottom (can't remember for sure though and can't test) - so if you're going for wide-as-possible support you will want to listen to jshint.

Something worth noting here is that if you use the `var` keyword to define your function, you will get an error - best explained by example:

This works (http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/kr8L825p/)

```
(function() {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch(ex) {
        alert("ahhhhh, what's going on?!?!?\n\n" + ex.message);
    }

    function foo() {
        alert("I was hoisted to the top of this scope before execution :)");
    }
})();
```

... but this doesn't (http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/kr8L825p/4/)

```
(function() {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch(ex) {
        alert("ahhhhh, what's going on?!?!?\n\n" + ex.message);
    }

    var foo = function() {
        alert("I was hoisted to the top of this scope before execution :)");
    }
})();
```