# JavaScript JSHint - 'close' is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I don't know why but some words that I use as function names get a lint error of being defined but never used.

For instance, the code below returns error:

```
// I am using AngularJS
$scope.close = close;

function close() {
    /* Code here */
}
```

But this does not:

```
// I am using AngularJS
$scope.close2 = close2;

function close2() {
    /* Code here */
}
```

The error is on the line `function close()`. Why is this such a special name? How can I mute this error?

Comment: Nothing really, just that the `$scope` function name is the same. Yeah it makes no sense that I included it, i'll remove it now

Comment: If you do the assignment after the declaration, the error goes away… There seems to be something special about the identifier "close", note that the window object also has a *close* method.

Comment: I have set `latedef` to `noFunc` so I can declare my function name after assignment. But you are right, it does go away. But why is it just that function name? The second cause (`close2`) works fine

Comment: Best practices you should hoist your function declarations anyway, then bugs like this won't happen.

Comment: @AlienWebguy, this is coding style was recommended by John Papa for AngularJS https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide. It really does make a HUGE difference when you follow that guiding style.

Comment: John Papa is not Douglas Crockford. Making all those named functions like that requires you to wrap all your controller files in IFFE's which makes everything nested 4 more spaces.. its a trade off. I don't agree with it, but I see it as a common practice in Ng core and even ngMaterial so what do I know.

Comment: @AlienWebguy, fair enough. Okay thanks for your feedback. I would vote yours as an answer if you post this.

Comment: I don't think it's a suitable answer, just a way around your issue. I'd like to know what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: I'd suggest one way is to not create global functions with names that are the same as default window properties, like *close* or *alert*. Then you can use either style and it won't upset the linter (or hinter). ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: Answer has been heavily edited)

### Summary

[John Papa says to use `latedef` in JSHint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26321623/1028230) and, at least implicitly, to ignore JSLint issues.  (`latedef` defined [here](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#latedef).)

I believe there's a plays-nicely solution (see below), however, that includes the advantages of Papa's suggested style with code that lints in JSHint *and* JSLint.

JSHint is "wrong" not to complain about `close2`. JSLint catches it exactly like you'd expect.

---

### `close` but not `close2` is a JSHint problem

For what it's worth, if you paste your code (jslint formatted Pasteee with both close & close2 [**here**](http://paste.ee/p/NC5KD)) into [JSLint.com](http://jslint.com), **both** `close` and `close2` cause errors. If you're not seeing an error for `close2`, I'm guessing it's JSHint's problem, but it'd be more useful to see exactly what you're linting through JSHint (in context) to know for sure.

So `close` is not a special name to JSLint.  I would like to see your "actual" code in context to see if JSLint would say something similar

Just to be clear, this breaks on [JSLint.com](http://jslint.com):

```
/*jslint sloppy:true, white:true */
/*global $scope */

$scope.close2 = close2;

function close2() {
    return "something";
}
```

That **will** produce `'close2' was used before it was defined. $scope.close2 = close2;`

If you want to know why JSHint is, I believe, breaking, we can go JSHint code spelunking, but to answer your JS**L**int tag (at least) the behavior you're seeing isn't happening.

---

### How to fix

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288367/does-jshint-understand-angular) on exactly what you're discussing here, where [John Papa says to use `latedef` in JSHint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26321623/1028230). One way around the linting issue is to ignore Papa and [define the function first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26288458/1028230), but, as you mention in your [comment, below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286700/javascript-jshint-close-is-defined-but-never-used/27295783?noredirect=1#comment43073121_27295783), that's not ideal.

So here's the best compromise I could come up with...

1. Declare, but don't define, variables that will hold functions.
2. Insert your Angular directive
3. Define your functions from 1.

That definitely mutes the JSHint error, since the code that caused it isn't there any more. If I was doing Angular and needed to follow Papa-style, that's what I'd do to keep Crockford's blessing.

Example:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    // 1. Declare your function names. Minimally spammy!
    var theController;

    // 2. Directive
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myAppCtrl', theController);

    // 3. *Define* the functions. No `latedef` needed, and JSLint compliant.
    // Keeps "the list of calls at the top of the page" and allows you to
    // "jump to each definition if you need more details". QED? ;^)
    theController = function () {
        return "so jslint doesn't complain about empty blocks";
    };
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So yes, I have already globally set the sloppy and `latedef` so that I can assign a function before declaring it. The reason why you would want to do that (as oppose to just directly `$scope.close = function() ...` is because when a directive gets long, its a lot better to see the list of calls at the top of the page. Then jump to each definition if you need more details.

Comment: I'll edit heavily & paste in the code [I put on that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27296661/1028230) here -- declaring your functions' variables, putting in your directive, then defining the functions seems the best lint-friendly compromise.

Comment: I think all I'm missing now, if you don't want to stop at the JSH/Lint-friendly solution at the end, is *specifically* why JSHint is broken. That'd be interesting, but the convention at the end gives you lintable code and avoids that error. That said, let me know if we need to go code-spelunking in JSHint. I've only played in JSLint to this point, so it might be fun.