# Jslint setup for angular style guide for john papa is not working

Tags: angularjs

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#function-declarations-to-hide-implementation-details john gave his styleguide on angular its superb but the problem here is when I turn on the linter it shows me error of out of scope I cannot find any right way to deal with it. I cannot globally turn off out of scope.

```
(function () {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('TimeSheetApp.Profile', [])
        .controller('ProfileController', ['$scope', '$log', ProfileController]);

        function ProfileController($scope, $log) {
        $log.log("ProfileController loaded!");
        }
}());
```

And the linters output is

#1 'ProfileController' is out of scope.
    .controller('ProfileController', ['$scope', '$log', ProfileController]); // Line 6, Pos 61
 #2 Unused '$scope'.
    function ProfileController($scope, $log) { // Line 8, Pos 32

Comment: because `$scope` is not being used by code.

Answer (score 0):

see [Does jshint understand Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288367/does-jshint-understand-angular)

another workaround is to add `//ignore jslint` at the end of the line