# jshintConfig in package.json for angular project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, jshint, package.json

I am trying to configure jshint in package.json. I am using gulp and this is an angular project. I have added the below code in package.json

```
"jshintConfig":{
 "globals":{
  "angular": false
  }
}
```

But it seems jshint is not picking it up.
I did this to avoid the below error I was getting on running jshint

```
line 3  col 1  'angular' is not defined.
```

Comment: Which text editor are you currently using?

Comment: IntelliJ. But I didnt get how both are related?

Comment: Text editors are configured to read `jshint` configurations from different locations.

Comment: how does text editor matter when I am running it through terminal. Where does IDE come into picture?

Comment: If the answer below did not solve it: How about posting the whole `package.json` plus directory structure and command line input and output?

Answer (score 2):

Not all editors support reading jshint configuration from package.json.

For example, check out [this discussion for Atom](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-jshint/issues/25) in which they ended up implementing it after all (it wasn't supported in the beginning).

I would invite you to move your settings outside package.json and use the .jshintrc approach instead. In fact, even jshint itself is using that approach as you can see [in their repo](https://github.com/jshint/jshint). The .jshintrc is more dynamic, as you can place different .jshintrc files per folder and fine-tune your settings (e.g. different settings for your unit tests folder and different settings for your client side scripts).

Answer (score 0):

An example of it working is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26288458/1587329, which uses `"angular": true`. Alternatively, you can try to use

```
"jshintConfig": {
  "predef": ["angular"]
}
```